# Do native speaker understand "I know to swim."?

Tags: to-infinitive

I want to know the difference between 'I know swimming.' and 'I know to swim.'
Do native speakers understand the meaning of the sentence 'I know to swim.'
I didn't see the sentence like 'I know to swim.'
but I think that(I know to swim) is a right sentence grammatically.
Is the sentence (I know to swim.) not acceptable but understandable by a native speaker?

Comment: Both sentences are understandable, but neither are correct. You should say, "I know **how** to swim."

Comment: @JasonB - "I know swimming" could be considered correct if the person was trying to say "I know a lot about swimming."

Comment: Some foreign speakers have to make a leap when learning English because their languages use the verb equivalent to "know" when discussing the ability to read, write, swim, fly, play a musical instrument, play a game, etc, in situations where English uses 'can'.